# vue.js show data next to each other and not under

Tags: vue.js

I am currently trying to present some data from my API. I use vue.js and wand to show the data from multiple robots. The id from the robot should be on top and then the data from that robot should follow. My problem is that the data is just presented underneath each other and not next to each other. Does somebody know what I could do? Note that the second robot with the id two currently has no feeds. Thank you so much.

this is how it looks like now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaN9U.png

and this is the code:

```
<div id="robot_data" v-for="maschine in userdaten.maschinen" :key="maschine.maschineId">
       {{maschine.maschineId}}

       <div id="feeds" v-for="feed in maschine.feeds" :key="feed.feedsId">
            <div id="second" v-if="feed.datum >= '2020-10-03' + ' 00:00:00' && 
                 feed.datum <= '2020-10-03' + '23:59:59'"style="font-size: 16px">

                   {{feed.feedsId}} - {{feed.datum}}
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when using `v-for`, `class` should be used instead of `id` (should be unique). You can solve the problem by styling `.robot_data` with `float: left;`:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    userdaten: {
      maschinen: [
        { maschineId:1, 
          feeds: [ 
            { feedsId:1, datum: '2020-10-03 23:50:00' }, 
            { feedsId:2, datum: '2020-10-03 00:00:00' } 
          ] 
        },
        { maschineId:2, 
          feeds: [
            { feedsId:1, datum: '2020-10-03 23:40:00' }, 
          ] 
        }
      ]
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.robot_data { float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="robot_data" v-for="maschine in userdaten.maschinen" :key="maschine.maschineId">
    <strong>{{maschine.maschineId}}</strong>
    <div class="feeds" v-for="feed in maschine.feeds" :key="feed.feedsId">
      <div class="second" v-if="feed.datum >= '2020-10-03' + ' 00:00:00' && feed.datum <= '2020-10-03' + '23:59:59'" style="font-size: 16px">
        {{feed.feedsId}} - {{feed.datum}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```